# JVM default configuration for javaagent

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, jvm

In my system whenever any program call java, it should be start with my javaagent. I can give -javaagent:MyJavaagentJar when I am running java program.

But, I am expecting -javaagent:MyJavaagentJar argument should be passed automatically.

Is there any configuration in java for this?